# Got this message while trying to update kodi isengard to the latest 17.3 build

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kodi_2%3a17.4+git20170822.1009-final-0xenial_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kodi-bin_2%3a17.4+git20170822.1009-final-0xenial_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What command did you use that provided this output? Please [edit] it into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading Kodi, you need to remove the previous version compleatly, run

```
sudo apt purge kodi kodi-bin kodi-data 
rm -r .kodi
```

Now you can install the latest version of Kodi from the repo.